# How to make an almost empty <div> reach the size of the viewport without overflowing?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my personal page, separated by , where each one would be the size of the viewport. (The first would have my "logo" in the background only, the second my personal information and so on.).
However, when I get this size, I realized that I can't align my button (an link) because there is an overflow. And when I manage to get the overflow, the first div becomes tiny. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <title>Carlos P.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="initialDiv">
        <a href="#secondDiv"
          ><img
            class="whiteArrowDown"
            src="/img/white-arrow-down-circle.svg"
            alt="arrow down"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div id="secondDiv">
        <h1 class="title">Hi, i'm Carlos!</h1>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Style below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "232mksdroundlight";
  src: url("/src/232MKSD.woff2") format("woff2");
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#initialDiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: #383431;
  background-image: url(/img/myLogo.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.whiteArrowDown {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#secondDiv {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
p {
  font-family: "232mksdroundlight";
  color: #383431;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is also the JSFiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/CarlosPaps/v7aLcdqp/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is use JS to set the width and height of each section to the browser height and width this will give any user a full window view of your site. I would also probably set a minimum height as well in case users have a shorter window. Using overflow-x on the body will ensure no horizontal scroll bars appear though they shouldn't.

```js
var contentBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName('content'); // Get all sections
var blockArray = Object.values(contentBlocks); //Convert to array for forEach

const windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; //grab client/borwser width
const windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; //grab client/browser height


//forEach to go through each item and set their width and height
blockArray.forEach(function(block) { 
  block.style.width = windowWidth+"px";
  block.style.height = windowHeight+"px";
});
```

```css
body { 
height:100%;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
background-color: #aaa;
min-height: 600px;
}

.content:nth-of-type(2) {
background-color: #bbb;
}

.content:nth-of-type(3) {
background-color: #ccc;
}

.content:nth-of-type(4) {
background-color: #ddd;
}

.content:nth-of-type(5) {
background-color: #eee;
}

.content:nth-of-type(6) {
background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
```